# Pympler: Reliable on Python 3.6?

Tags: python, profiling, python-3.6

Is Pympler 0.5 (current version) stable and reliable on Python 3.6 and 3.5?

The [current Mac port is 3.4](https://trac.macports.org/log/trunk/dports/python/py-pympler/Portfile), and the [documentation](https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) refers to up to 3.2.

Given this package does rather a deep dive into Python behavior, could anyone comment as to its stability status for latest Pythons?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for Pympler 0.5](https://archive.is/0eZ31#selection-117.2-117.70):
Pympler has been tested with Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5.

Comment: Then this page needs updating: 
    https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
since it refers to 3.2 max.

Too bad it hasn't been checked against 3.6, which is rather common now.

Comment: Did it answer your question?

Comment: No, because I asked about Python 3.6 compatibility, which the answer left unaddressed. However, I note that the current documentation lists up to 3.7 compatibility, so we're golden.

Comment: Well, it mentioned the version it is tested with, and 3.6 is not in the list, so it could not be considered "stable and reliable" for 3.6.